# MongoDB range query on manually created _id

Tags: mongodb, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have a use case where storing an _id that is a composite of the following would be immensely useful:

1. 96 bit int
2. 96 bit int
3. 96 bit int ObjectID

This works out as a 36 byte ASCII string. It will be byte reversed to become big endian.

I would like to query "Give me all documents where _id starts with {1} concatenate {2}." This would return documents where _id matches components 1 & 2 above, with any 3.

Yes, this is a Cassandra approach. The rest of the query I have can only be done realistically in MongoDB.

How can I do this?

For reference, I am using C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your IDs saved as a 36-byte ascii strings, you can use a [regular expression](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions) match to find prefix substrings in the index.

The caveats for efficiently using an index with regular expressions in MongoDB are that:

- the regex match should be left-rooted (which will be the case for your "_id starts with" search)
- indexes are case-sensitive

The query would be similar to:

```
/* Assumption: comp1 and comp2 are ASCII string representations
   that can be combined for a key prefix */

var spec = new Document("_id", new MongoRegex(string.Format("^{0}{1}", comp1, comp2)));
collection.Find(spec)
```

Comment: One question: ASCII of course is binary, so spans the whole 0 - 255 range. Will this effect the regex?

Comment: @IanC: MongoDB regexes support UTF-8; ASCII should not be an issue.  The [string format in BSON](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) is also UTF-8.

Comment: As noted in the related discussion on the [mongodb-user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/rVQqR2QByNo), you also have the option of creating a [composite _id](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-The%5CidField) which could be {Int, Int, ObjectID} rather than creating a single string _id.

Comment: thanks, I noted that. Although I would need 5 components to handle 96 & 96 bits & ObjectID. If that has no adverse effect on query speed, then it suite me fine.